# Python regex match to parse html

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm playing with python and I would like to solve the following problem with a regex:

I would like to parse html from a Website with regex.
I get the site in a String. I take every line of the site in a loop.

```
for line in html.splitlines():
    #print line
    matchObj = re.match( r'<h1(.*)>', line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
        print matchObj.group()
```

I would like to match every line which matches with
`<h1 class="hidden offscreen" tabindex="0"> anyContent </h1>`

Comment: [Obligatory link - Don't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1561176)

Comment: What do you need a good hint for? What does/does not work for you? Have you taken a look a the documentation of the re module?

Comment: Use the HTMLParser module. It's not that hard if you look at their examples.

Comment: why each second person want to parse html with regexp's?

Comment: @InbarRose [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272): choose answers not non-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive version would be

```
html = '<h1 class="hidden offscreen" tabindex="0"> anyContent </h1>'
print re.search('(?is)<h1[^>]*>(.+?)</h1>', html).group(1)
```

Note that this assumes valid html, if this might not be the case it's safer to use a parser:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
print BeautifulSoup(html).find("h1").text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY want to parse such content you can do it with a regex along these lines:

```
<h1 class="hidden offscreen" tabindex="0">(?p<content>.*?)</h1>
```

Do NOT try to expand this to other tags or cases. HTML uses a more complex grammar than regex can handle.

I agree with Hai Vu's comment, use the HTMLParser module. Or beautiful soup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old script I wrote back when. It should get you started. Pay attention to `attrs` from the `handle_starttag()` method.

```
import HTMLParser

class HeadersParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HeadersParser, self).__init__()
        self.in_header = False
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag.lower() == 'h1':
            self.in_header = True
    def handle_endtag(self, attrs):
        self.in_header = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_header:
            print '{}'.format(data)
            
with open('sample.html') as f:
    html_contents = f.read()
    
parser = HeadersParser()
parser.feed(html_contents)
```